# jQuery stop ajax running asynchrously

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asynchronous

Is there a way to prevent ajax running async?

jQuery:

```
var returnValue = false;
        var appCount = 0;

        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "getBookedAppointmentCountByDoctorAndDate.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function (response){
                appCount = response;
                //alert(appCount);
                if(appCount >= 6){

                    returnValue = true;
                }
            }
        });
        return returnValue;
```

I have an if statement in my code that checks the return value of this function. Because Ajax runs async, the if statement is continuing before the return value is set. Any ideas or suggestions of other methods to use to return php value?

```
if (blah($(this)) === true) {
                    alert("blah");
                } else { ...
```

Comment: There is a way, but the real answer here is, **you should never do it** !

Comment: In your request, you must do async: false http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: You never never should use sync methods on browser because freeze the main thread. To "return" a valud when the ajax call end you should use a callback (or, more advance, return a promise).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add parameter `async: false` to ajax parameters http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/, browser will be inactive while ajax request, so it is not good decision.

Better move `if statement` to ajax success function, or make function with `if statement` and call it in success function.

Comment: I think you mean `async: false`

Comment: Please mark this as the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

You are using this snippet inside a function, right? Since you have a `return` statement, I'm guessing so.

You can not return the value that is going to be determined in an async task. What you could do is to pass a callback function to this function and when the value is determined, pass the value to that function and call it.

```
function myFunc(callback) {

    var returnValue = false;
    var appCount = 0;

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "getBookedAppointmentCountByDoctorAndDate.php",
        data: dataString,
        success: function (response){
            appCount = response;
            //alert(appCount);
            if(appCount >= 6){
                returnValue = true;
            }
            callback(returnValue);
        }
    });
}



myFunc(function (value) {
    console.log(value);
    // do what ever you want with `value`
})
```

Another approach is to use `Promise`. In case you want to use jQuery's promises, here is the [documentations](https://api.jquery.com/promise/)